# In Automator, can I combine 2 or more variables into a new variable?

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, automator

First off, let´s set the scene. I am trying to **make a small applet (.app)** to include in a DMG-file for distribution. The .app file will only **activate when a user drags a folder with my product-files onto it**. Then the folder is supposed to be copied into the current user´s **/Music/MY CUSTOM PATH/**. Any user on any system, that happens to be logged in.

This is *similar* to having a *relative symlink/alias* to the `/Applications` folder, like when you install google chrome or any app that comes in a dmg.

So, by using the Automator action **"copy finder items"** I dragged the *pre-defined variable* **"variables > Locations > Music"** to the action and that works well on any system, by copying any file you drag onto my .app into the users `~/Music` folder.

Great. But my app goes into the folder `~/Music/Audio Music Apps/Patches/my-folder`. **Now what?**

I have tried to find anything related to "combine folder paths" or "combine variables" or "append..." but with no luck. I´m to Automator so don´t know all the tricks. Please help me make it possible to create an app that can copy into ANY sub-folder of ANY user´s home folder, on any system.

Comment: Automator doesn't have any default actions to manipulate variables or build file paths, so you will need to use a third party action or roll your own by using a script in a **Run AppleScript** action.

Comment: @red_menace True, I realized that after much tinkering. But the answer I gave the question is the same result as combining variables, not really, but in my own case. I tried some applescript and bash/shell alternatives but the answer was to simple. God. Forgot about Apple´s drag-n-dropiness. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, there is no "*combine variables*" action per say in automator, but you can add a **custom text variable**, and **drag another variable from the library variables into any part of the text in the `value` field**. In my case, needing to combine paths to folders, this is the same thing.

1. create a "**text**" variable from `Variables > Text & Data > Text`.
2. Drag the desired variable into the "Value" field anywhere you need it.

Done. You can now add the **text**-variable you just made to the "**copy Finder items**" action as the destination. This enables you to use it on **ANY system**, **ANY user**. Very handy for an installation file, or any dock-app with custom paths (but still relative paths to whatever user is logged in).

[image]

Comment: how to you add a newline in the text variable?